# Easy way to animate views transition between activities

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

Is there a simple and generic way to animate views while transitioning between activities? Some function that only needs the source and target views without writing any code which is specific to each transition.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I've found a generic and quite simple way to animate views on transition using these functions:

```
private static final String VIEW_TRANSITION_PREFIX = "view_transition_";

public static void startActivityAnimatingViews(@NonNull final Activity activity, @NonNull final Intent intent, View... views) {
        Log.d(TAG, "startActivityAnimatingViews() called with: activity = [" + activity + "], intent = [" + intent + "], views = [" + Arrays.deepToString(views) + "]");
        if (views != null) {
            final List<Pair<View, String>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
                final View view = views[i];
                final String transitionName = getTransitionNameForView(i);
                view.setTransitionName(transitionName);
                Pair<View, String> pair = Pair.create(view, transitionName);
                pairs.add(pair);
            }

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //noinspection unchecked
                    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, pairs.toArray(new Pair[pairs.size()]));
                    activity.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
                }
            });

        }else{
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public static void onCreateActivityAnimatingViews(View... views) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateActivityAnimatingViews() called with: views = [" + Arrays.deepToString(views) + "]");
        if (views != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
                views[i].setTransitionName(getTransitionNameForView(i));
            }
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    private static String getTransitionNameForView(int index) {
        return VIEW_TRANSITION_PREFIX + index;
    }
```

To use these functions you need to call `startActivityAnimatingViews` when you want to start a new activity and pass it the views in the current activity you want to animate. Then, in `onCreate` of the second activity call `onCreateActivityAnimatingViews` with the targets of the views **in the exact same order**.

To simplify, here's an example of how to animate 2 views from one activity to another:

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UiUtils.startActivityAnimatingViews(FirstActivity.this, new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class), FirstActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.first_view1), FirstActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.first_view2));
            }
        });
    }
}

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        UiUtils.onCreateActivityAnimatingViews(findViewById(R.id.second_view1), findViewById(R.id.second_view2));
    }
}
```

Note that some flags on the `intent` like `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` or `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` may prevent the animation from working.